# Integrate Map in Fragment instead of Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to add Google Map in a fragment which is inside Main Activity.
But I get an error in the below statements.

1. **this**  `fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);`
2. **getApplicationContext()**
   `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude()`
3. **getSupportFragmentManager()**  `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);`
   The same code works in an Activity. As this is coded in a Fragment, what are the changes that should be done?

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                if(location != null){
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude()
                            +""+currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapFragment.this);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here.");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    fetchLastLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting? post the error log along with the question

Comment: @akhilesh0707  What can be used instead of "activity: this" in a fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer. Whoever finds trouble in this can use the below way:
Instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
```

I coded as,

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false); 
return v;
```

and then

1. Instead of using `this` use `getActivity()`
2. Instead of `getApplicationContext()` use `v.getApplicationContext()`
3. Instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` use `v.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getActivity()` instead of `this` here

```
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

and use `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

third problem `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Update

Try

```
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient((Context)getActivity());
```

Comment: "Try using getActivity() instead of this here" - this doesn't work. It says "Unreachable Statement".

Comment: 2. getActivity().getApplicationContext() 
3.  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
I tried it this way for the 2nd and 3rd and it worked. Thank you.
 But the first statement is still underlined in red

Comment: you did it like this : `fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());`